# Angular messenger service error TS2769: No overload matches this call

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to send products to cart component using a messenger service.
'Product' is simply a class containing product attributes, I was able to log it to console in cart component but when setting up the subscribe method  the 'product:Product' line in the subscribe method of the cart component causes the following error message to pop up

```
src/app/cart/cart.component.ts:31:7 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver<unknown> | ErrorObserver<unknown> | CompletionObserver<unknown> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error...
```

This is my messenger service file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject,Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from './product';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessengerService {

  subject=new Subject()

  constructor() { }
  sendMsg(product:any){
    console.log(product)
    this.subject.next(product)

  }

  getMsg(){

    return this.subject.asObservable()
  }
}
```

This is cart component file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{MessengerService} from 'src/app/messenger.service';
import {Product} from 'src/app/product';
import{CartItem} from 'src/app/cartitem';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart',
  templateUrl: './cart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart.component.css']
})
export class CartComponent implements OnInit {

 cartItems:any[]=[
    
  ] 

  cartTotal=0;

 


  constructor(private msg:MessengerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.msg.getMsg().subscribe((product: Product) => {
      this.addProductToCart(product)
    })
  }

  addProductToCart(product:Product)
  {
    console.log(product)
    this.cartItems.push(
      {
        productId:product.id,
        productName:product.name,
        qty:1,
        price:product.price

      }
    )
  this.cartTotal=0
    this.cartItems.forEach(
      item=>{
        this.cartTotal+=(item.qty*item.price)
      }
    )


  }

}
```

Comment: try `getMsg(): Observable<Product> {`

Answer (score 1):

Please add the type of Subject.
subject= new Subject();

Comment: subject= new Subject<Product>();

Answer (score -1):

Just add the type of Subject.
subject= new Subject();
It will resolve the problem

Comment: subject= new Subject<Product>(); you can refer this one

Comment: Remove one of your Answers, they're basically the same. You are also able to edit your Answers, there should be no need to add a comment. You can just edit it in to your Answer.